# Recognizing a Martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-expectation, martingales

Under which conditions is the stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t=0,1,...,T}$ a martingale? Demonstrate and explain clearly for each case below. If it is not necessarily a martingale, provide a counterexample.

$E_t[X_s] = X_t$ for $0 \leq t \leq s \leq T$

$E_0[X_t] = X_0$ for $0 \leq t \leq T$

$E_t[X_T] = X_t$ for $0 \leq t \leq T$

I am having a bit of a hard time figuring this out.  My hunch is that, as long as (1) $E[|X_t|] < \infty$ and (2) $X_t$ is adapted to a filtration $F_T$, then all of the stochastic processes listed above are Martingales because they are just equivalent ways of stating the first property of Martingales, that is, $E[X_T|F_t] = X_t$ for $0 \leq t \leq T$ .  Therefore, a counterexample could be anything that does not satisfy properties (1) and (2).  Is this correct?  If not, why? Thanks!